# I want my NPC to look in the direction I am standing at. How would I do this most effectively?

Tags: java, slick2d

I'm currently building a 2D game with Slick2D, and right now I'm implementing my first NPC.

I already have the sprites, I was able to draw him, did the collisions, and so on, but now I want to add the feature which makes the NPC look into the direction I am currently at, when I am entering a certain range around the NPC (Which would be 2 tiles left, diagonal, right, up and down, but because I want it to be exact, I'm using the x coordinates, so for every tile I would be checking 32x32 possibilities)

To get this a little bit more clear I drew a picture:

[image]

The numbers are the x and y coordinates, while my NPC is placed at 704,704.

The problem I have is that I don't know how to check all the coordinates effectively, without having to write 5000 lines of if's. The 2 left diagonal lines, which could both be interpreted as "NPC looks up" and "NPC looks left" would make him look left, same with the 2 right ones, which would make him look right.

Is there some clever method I can use, or should I just go back and divide the x and y by 32 so I only check if my player is on a certain tile? That would be less precise, though.

Comment: Is there no better tag for your question I wonder? Your question is not in any way related to either Java or slick2d, it is a (very interesting) generic game programming theory question most likely answered by math.

Comment: @Gimby I wasn't sure, I was hoping someone could provide information on a method out of the java or Slick2D library or redirect me to others. Mainly because I thought there are some people around who have experience in that field or came across a similar problem already. But yes, I have to agree that math could possibly provide an algorithm to solve this.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you should use [`atan2`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)`(your.y - npc.y, your.x - npc.x)` to find angle at which the npc need to look.

Comment: Do you have diagonal directions or just north,south,west,east?